# Hibernate - Unable to acquire JDBC Connection(CannotCreateTransactionException)

Tags: java, linux, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I have a tomcat server which had a "too many open files" problem on Linux.
I tried to fix it by increasing the ulimit from 4096 to 8192.

```
sudo vim /etc/security/limits.conf

* - nofile 8192
```

So now it looks like this:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 23820
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 8192
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 8192
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

And the process limits of tomcat are:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max processes             8192                 23820                processes 
Max open files            8192                 8192                 files     
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       23820                23820                signals   
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
Max nice priority         0                    0                    
Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

After it runs for a while, the open files are increased to 5000.
And it starts throwing exceptions every time when I try to insert/update data:

```
2017-05-29 10:20:56 [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]-[ERROR] - An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
2017-05-29 10:20:56 [mvc.controller.exception.resolver.Log4jExceptionResolver]-[DEBUG] - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String mvc.controller.service.v2.HotTopicsPutController.put(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.util.List<mvc.model.bean.form.v2.ArticleDataForm>,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
2017-05-29 10:20:56 [mvc.controller.exception.resolver.Log4jExceptionResolver]-[ERROR] - org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:541)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.insertOrUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at mvc.controller.service.v2.HotTopicsPutController.put(HotTopicsPutController.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.beginTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:401)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:499)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:527)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:99)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@235ca7eb -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1317)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 61 more
```

It looks like the system is still blocking tomcat to create connection to the database.

Here are my server.xml and hibernate configurations:

server.xml(only allows https requests)

```
...

<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" 
               redirectPort="8443"/>

<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false" 
               scheme="https" 
               keystoreFile="/xxx/ooo/yyy"
               keystorePass="xxxxxxxxxx" 
               keystoreType="xxxxxxx"
               keyAlias="1"
               secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" SSLEnabled="true">

</Connector>

...
```

spring-hibernate:

```
<!-- Direct JDBC DataSource -->
    <bean id="jdbcDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">

        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />

...

        <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="60" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="12" />
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="1800" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="600" />
        <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="300" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="100" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="30" />
        <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000" />
        <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false" />
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="10000" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="false" />
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1;" />
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="10" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="1000" />
        <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="25" />

...

</bean>
```

And this is my build.gradle:

```
    // Spring framework
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.3.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.webflow:spring-webflow:2.4.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.session:spring-session:1.2.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.10.2.RELEASE'

    // Hibernate ORM
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.5.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.2.4.Final'
    compile 'com.mchange:c3p0:0.9.5.2'
    compile 'javax.transaction:jta:1.1'
    compile 'com.atomikos:transactions:4.0.4'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.3'
```

Is it related to the `keep alive sockets` problem?
Because it never decreased, so the open files number keeps increasing.
I have to restart tomcat every week to close the `keep alive sockets`.
How should I do to fix this issue?
Why is there still a problem after I increased the open file limits?

Comment: Looks like you might have connection leak or connection pool deadlock.

Comment: Seems like your connection pool is getting exhausted. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614549/c3p0-unreturnedconnectiontimeout-in-production

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743958/connection-time-out-isues-after-inactivity-period could be helpful to you

Comment: That reminds me, I do have a `dead lock found` problem. So the dead lock keeps sockets alive, that's why it never decrease, right?